# Getting error while compiling code in react-Native

Tags: react-native

Hi i am getting error while i am compiling code through command , but code run using Android Studio.Below the error message

```
bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativePropRegistry` from `/home/rahul/React/Android /trixie/trixie/node_modules/native-base/dist/src/Utils/computeProps.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
  /home/rahul/React/Android /trixie/trixie/node_modules/native-base/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims
,   /home/rahul/React/Android /trixie/trixie/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims
,   /home/rahul/React/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims
```

My Package.JSON is which I have used in the project and getting above error message

```
     "dependencies": {
     "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "0.0.8",
     "axios": "^0.16.2",
     "native-base": "^2.3.1",
     "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
     "react-addons-update": "^15.6.0",
      "react-native": "^0.46.0",
     "react-native-checkbox": "^1.1.0",
      "react-native-cookie": "^0.1.1",
     "react-native-customisable-switch": "^0.1.0",
     "react-native-elements": "^0.14.0",
     "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.6.1",
     "react-native-geocoder": "^0.4.8",
     "react-native-google-places": "^2.4.1",
     "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.2.12",
     "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.3",
     "react-native-instagram-login": "^1.0.2",
     "react-native-instagram-oauth": "0.0.7",
     "react-native-looped-carousel": "^0.1.7",
     "react-native-maps": "^0.15.3",
     "react-native-modal": "^2.4.0",
     "react-native-permissions": "^1.0.0",
     "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.17",
     "react-native-slider": "^0.10.0",
     "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
     "react-native-xmpp": "^0.5.0",
     "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
     "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
      "redux": "^3.7.1",
      "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
     "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
     "superagent": "^3.5.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
     "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
     "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
     "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
     "jest": "20.0.4",
     "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
   },
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i think there is something wrong with your node_modules , basically it tells you that ReactNativePropRegistry doesn't exist , try to delete the node_modules using this :

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

if you can show us your code , it will be much easier for the others to know what's the issues

Answer (score 0):

I think it was version issue of react-native and native-base.

Please check following native-base issue.

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1029